# rsync: Exclude directory in one branch, but not in other

Tags: rsync

I would like to do a

```
rsync master slave
```

with the following restriction: The directory `master/foo/xxx` should be excluded from being copied, but the directory `master/bar/xxx` should be copied.

I can not write

```
rsync --exclude xxx master slave
```

because this would also exclude `master/bar/xxx`. To my surprise, I can also not use

```
rsync --exclude master/foo/xxx master slave
```

because it copies BOTH xxx directories (why?).

Of course I can revert to writing two rsync's:

```
rsync --exclude xxx master slave
rsync master/bar/xxx slave/bar/xxx
```

but I wonder whether this can't be done any simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is this:

```
rsync --exclude /foo/xxx master slave
```

Include/exclude rules beginning with `/` are relative to the root of the transfer (not the root of the filesystem).

Rules starting with other characters are matched to the end of each filename, so `foo/xxx` would work also, but might match directories you weren't expecting if there is a `foo` somewhere else in the directory tree.

Your command did *not* work because "master" is outside the root of the transfer.